# Nvidia 1080 ti VRM? SMD Identification

Tags: transistors, pcb, identification, surface-mount, gpu

I was hoping that some of you experts could help me identify a SMD on the back of a 1080 ti FE. This item was dropped and it appears has some damage done to it. I would like to replace the missing SMD if possible but having problems identifying what they are.

I know the part is still in production because I have identified it on the newer 2080 ti but still unable to find it.

I have attached the image of the back of the 1080ti. I have specified different sections. I am only Concerned about section A and B.

[image: Back of 1080TI]

Section A: This is were I believe two SOT-353 SMD's have been knocked off. I think I located a similar  circuit on the board that identifies the missing SMD. (Section B)

Section A:
[image: Section A:]

Section B:
[image]

I couldn't find anything on mouser or digikey that match the code.

Parts Symbol "VT"  there are two ".." under the "V" with a sideways "5" I have found possibilities on the internet but not sure if they are correct?

R1122N171B -- Linear voltage regulator IC

RT9198-20PBR -- LinearRegulatorIC

Any help would be appreciated.

Its not as detailed as my own but here is a reference pic of the back of the pcb.
[image: ref_back_pcb]
Thxs

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced there's parts knocked off the board there; I wouldn't expect to see reasonably normal solder fillets left. I would expect either the pad to be ripped off the board, or a clear indent in the solder fillet where the part leg used to be, or (part of) the part leg still left. On the other hand, if you look in the top left of the section A closeup, there might be a two-pin part missing there. The bottom pad there looks like it was ripped off the board.

Comment: There is also a resistor or capacitor missing, and it is also missing the component solder pad. If you know what component it was, you might be able to use a wire to bypass the missing pad and track. Seriously, you need to find a matching card or schematics or bill of materials to find out what the missing components are. You can't know what the missing components are just by looking another similar looking section on the board, it may not be identical.

Comment: Thanks Marcelm and Justme for the feedback. I am aware of the additional dmg you pointed out including the pulled pads. "Marcelm" If you look closely it appears that there are dimples where the legs were attached. I can see them better under the scope. I know I am making alot of assumptions and I don't have the expertise to get away with it. It just appears to me that A and B share the same components.

Comment: It may look like it, and they may be the same components, or not. If you don't know, then you don't know, unless you can gather evidence like looking another identical card with the components in place.

Comment: I found a HD reference photo of the back of the 1080ti FE. Its not as detailed as I would like but was able to confirm that part (A) of the board did have parts but not 100% I am able to make out the markings. Not sure if its wishful thinking or if I see the same markings.

Answer (score 1):

By searching VT5 SMD CODE you can get clues if you avoid the 1st ad hits.

MC74VHC1GT08 vt5 aCMOS level shifter AND gate

Comment: Thanks Tony for helping out with this. I appreciate everyone's input. Ok so I see you used the 5 as part of the identification. I didn't know if it was some other indicator. 

I will lookup this part number and do some more research on it. I have a lot to learn but its exciting to see such a great community willing to help out.